# Проблемы при подключении Bootstrap в React приложение

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap, reactjs

После установки пакета ReactStraр, прописываю строку

`import bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` в `index.js`. Проблема состоит в том, что сразу после того, как добавляю эту строку, у меня пропадают абсолютно все написанные до этого мною стили css для элементов и размер станицы уменьшается, при этом не могу никак изменить это. Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, хотя с Bootstrap был опыт. Для сравнения вид до подключения bootstrap и после. Я не понимаю, почему изменяется высота страницы, которую я никак не могу изменить. Подскажите, что я делаю не так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтоп, но.. Кавычка забыта только в вопросе или в скрипте тоже? Первое. Второе - именно этот способ подключения является наилучшим решением?

Comment: Приложите код `index.js` как Вы импортируете bootstrap. Скорее всего проблема в том что бутсрап импортируется последним и переписывает Ваши стили. Нужно просто изменить порядок импортов.